# Finding a count of rows in an arbitrary date range using Oracle

Tags: oracle, analytic-functions

The question I need to answer is this "What is the maximum number of page requests we have ever received in a 60 minute period?"

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
date_page_requested      date;
page                     varchar(80);
```

I'm looking for the MAX count of rows in any 60 minute timeslice.

I thought analytic functions might get me there but so far I'm drawing a blank.

I would love a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: What granularity for the 60 minute period? If a page request happened at '2011-09-15 08:30:59.535', should the 60 minute period be aligned on the '08', the '30', the '59', or the '535' (the hour, minute, second, or millisecond)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options in the answer that will work, here is one that uses Oracle's "[Windowing Functions with Logical Offset](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16579/analysis.htm#sthref1145)" feature instead of joins or correlated subqueries.

First the test table:

```
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table t pctfree 0 nologging as
  2  select date '2011-09-15' + level / (24 * 4) as date_page_requested
  3  from dual
  4* connect by level <= (24 * 4)
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (to_date('2011-09-15 11:11:11', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

T now contains a row every quarter hour for a day with one additional row at 11:11:11 AM. The query preceeds in three steps. Step 1 is to, for every row, get the number of rows that come within the next hour after the time of the row:

```
  1  with x as (select date_page_requested
  2          , count(*) over (order by date_page_requested
  3              range between current row
  4                  and interval '1' hour following) as hour_count
  5      from t)
```

Then assign the ordering by hour_count:

```
  6  , y as (select date_page_requested
  7          , hour_count
  8          , row_number() over (order by hour_count desc, date_page_requested asc) as rn
  9      from x)
```

And finally select the earliest row that has the greatest number of following rows.

```
 10  select to_char(date_page_requested, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')
 11      , hour_count
 12  from y
 13* where rn = 1
```

If multiple 60 minute windows tie in hour count, the above will only give you the first window.

Comment: Thank you very much. Several of these produced "correct" results, but this one produces those results incredibly fast, meaning I'll be able to adapt it to run over a much larger time frame quite successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need, the first row returned should have 
the hour with the highest number of pages.

```
select number_of_pages
      ,hour_requested
from (select to_char(date_page_requested,'dd/mm/yyyy hh') hour_requested
            ,count(*) number_of_pages
      from pages
      group by to_char(date_page_requested,'dd/mm/yyyy hh')) p
order by number_of_pages
```

Comment: That would work beautifully if the 60 minute time frames all began at the top of the hour (e.g., 15:00) and ended at the bottom of the hour (e.g., 15:59) but what if the 60 minute span of greatest activity was 22:29 to 23:28?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT TOP 1
       ranges.date_start,
       COUNT(data.page) AS Tally
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
               date_page_requested AS date_start,
               DATEADD(HOUR,1,date_page_requested) AS date_end
          FROM @Table) ranges
  JOIN @Table data
    ON data.date_page_requested >= ranges.date_start
   AND data.date_page_requested < ranges.date_end
 GROUP BY ranges.date_start
 ORDER BY Tally DESC
```

Comment: Note that that's SQL Server (T-SQL), but you should get the idea.

Comment: Nice. Addind `SELECT TOP 1` and `ORDER BY Tally DESC` will give only the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL, I'd first probably write something like this for a "window" aligned on the minute. You don't need OLAP windowing functions for this.

```
select w.ts, 
       date_trunc('minute', w.ts) as hour_start, 
       date_trunc('minute', w.ts) + interval '1' hour as hour_end,
       (select count(*) 
        from weblog 
        where ts between date_trunc('minute', w.ts) and 
                        (date_trunc('minute', w.ts) + interval '1' hour) ) as num_pages
from weblog w
group by ts, hour_start, hour_end
order by num_pages desc
```

Oracle also has a trunc() function, but I'm not sure of the format. I'll either look it up in a minute, or leave to see a friend's burlesque show.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ranges AS
    ( SELECT
          date_page_requested          AS StartDate,
          date_page_requested + (1/24) AS EndDate,
          ROWNUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_page_requested) AS RowNo 
      FROM 
          @Table
    ) 

SELECT 
    a.StartDate                 AS StartDate,
    MAX(b.RowNo) - a.RowNo + 1  AS Tally 
FROM 
    ranges a
  JOIN
    ranges b 
      ON  a.StartDate <= b.StartDate
      AND b.StartDate < a.EndDate
GROUP BY a.StartDate
       , a.RowNo
ORDER BY Tally DESC
```

---

or:

```
WITH ranges AS
    ( SELECT
          date_page_requested          AS StartDate,
          date_page_requested + (1/24) AS EndDate,
          ROWNUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_page_requested) AS RowNo 
      FROM 
          @Table
    ) 

SELECT 
    a.StartDate                      AS StartDate,
    ( SELECT MIN(b.RowNo) - a.RowNo  
      FROM ranges b
      WHERE b.StartDate > a.EndDate
    )                                AS Tally
FROM 
    ranges a
ORDER BY Tally DESC
```